# How does the kernel interacts with drivers and device tree?

Tags: kernel, drivers, devices, embedded, uart

I have an embedded linux system running on a board. I had, in the device tree, the uart device, and also a driver for that. In that case, after boot, I could see a /dev/ttymxc0 "file" in the /dev/ folder. Since I need to use the UART for other purposes, I commented that section from the device tree, and I can see that now this file is not in the /dev/ folder anymore (I am now using ssh to interact with the board).

I will, now, (for other reasons) have to create a new, far simpler driver to the UART built-in my kernel, where I plan do use writing on registers to interact with the uart. My plan is to develop a driver so that, in User space, I can interact with the UART via the functions ioctl() and read().

However, I am very lost on what to do and how to begin. I couldn't find anywhere in the driver a reference or something that calls the mknode to create the device file, so I suspect that the kernel creates it somehow, maybe after it looks in the device tree? The problem is that in the original source code I coudln't find any mention of "ttymxc0" neither in the device tree, neither in the drivers code, anywhere.

I am unsure of what a driver *should actually do*. I've been reading a lot and I know that it will guide the kernel's interactions with the hardware. I've been reading a lot of questions in this site but I am still unsure on how does evreything links, interacts and add up *in practice*.

**tl;dr**: I want to write a simple driver for UART so that I can interact from user space using functions like ioctl and read, but I don't know what exactly the driver code should contain, how does it interact with the kernel and device tree, and how does it call mknode to create a device file in /dev/.